# Separating axes theorem problem

Tags: collision-detection, mathematics, vector, separating-axis-theorem

I´ve been following this tutorial : http://www.dyn4j.org/2010/01/sat/ to help me understand and implement the SAT for collision detection in my games as I want to add a support for polygons. However, I´m facing troubles with the overlap function(to determine whether two projections overlap or not). Pieces of code:

```
class Polygon {
    public:
        std::vector<vec2> vertices;
        std::vector<vec2> edges;
        std::vector<vec2> axes;

        Polygon(){}

        Polygon(std::vector<vec2> list) :
            vertices(list)
        {
            init();
        }

        void init() {

            for (std::size_t i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++) {

                vec2 edge = vertices[i] - vertices[i + 1 == vertices.size() ? 0 : i + 1];

                edges.push_back(edge);

                axes.push_back(edges.back().perp()); // its just (x,y) => (y,-x)
            }

        }
```

The projecting function:

```
    vec2 project(vec2& axis) {

        double min = axis.dot(vertices[0]);
        double max = min;

        for (std::size_t i = 1; i < vertices.size(); i++)
        {
            double p = axis.dot(vertices[i]);

            if (p < min)
                min = p;
            else if (p > max)
                max = p;
        }

        return vec2(min, max);
    }
```

And finally a function to determine if they collide or not:

```
bool collide(Polygon& poly1, Polygon& poly2)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < poly1.axes.size(); i++)
    {
        vec2 proj1 = poly1.project(poly1.axes[i]);
        vec2 proj2 = poly2.project(poly1.axes[i]);

        if (!proj1.overlap(proj2))
            return false;
    }

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < poly2.axes.size(); i++)
    {
        vec2 proj1 = poly1.project(poly2.axes[i]);
        vec2 proj2 = poly2.project(poly2.axes[i]);

        if (!proj1.overlap(proj2))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

How would you implement the overlap function? I found someone elses solution using this overlap function :

```
bool overlap(const vec2& vector) {

    vec2 diffVector(x - vector.x, y - vector.y);

    if (diffVector.magnitude < magnitude)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

but its not working correctly. Is the error somewhere else or? 
Also im using for tets :

```
std::vector<cd::vec2> vertices{ {-2.0f,2.0f},{ -1.0f,0.0f },{ 2.0f,0.0f },{2.0f,2.0f },{ -1.0f,3.0f } };
cd::Polygon poly1(vertices);

std::vector<cd::vec2> vertices2{ { 0.0f,-2.0f },{ 0.0f,-3.0f },{ 2.0f,-3.0f },{ 2.0f,-2.0f },{ 1.0f,1.0f } };
cd::Polygon poly2(vertices2); And it ouputs me they don´t collide even when they should collide. Thanks!
```

**Edit1**
(due to the first answer)
Adding a small screenshot showing a situation where green and red polygons just touch eachother, however the algorithm says they do not collide.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing the overlap like that assumes the order of the overlaps.

If you instead try to find the smallest `min` and the biggest `max` and then compare those it should work;

```
bool overlap(const vec2& b) {
    double minA;
    double maxA;
    double minB;
    double maxB;
    if (x < b.x) {
        minA = x;
        maxA = y;
        minB = b.x;
        maxB = b.y;
    }
    else {
        minA = b.x;
        maxA = b.y;
        minB = x;
        maxB = y;
    }

    return !(maxA <= minB || minA >= maxB);
}
```

To find the depth of the penetration something like might do the trick;

```
float getOverlapDepth(const vec2& b) {
  float minA;
  float maxA;
  float minB;
  float maxB;
  if (x < b.x) {
    minA = x;
    maxA = y;
    minB = b.x;
    maxB = b.y;
  }
  else {
    minA = b.x;
    maxA = b.y;
    minB = x;
    maxB = y;       
  }

  if (maxA <= minB || minA >= maxB) {
    return 0.0f;
  }
  else {
    if (minB > minA && maxB < maxA) {
      return 100.0f; // Or some other high value to indicate complete overlap
    }
    else {
      return maxA - minB;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: yay! it looks like it works now! (havent tried many different polygons yet). But I noticed one thing, if the two polygons only touch each other (i will edit question so you will see a screenshot describing the situation better) the algorithm says that they are colliding. However if I translate the top vertex of the green polygon for example vec(0.0f,0.01f) it says they collide. How would you fix that? Thanks.

Comment: @Pins You can measure the depth of the penetration and if it is very close to 0 you ignore the overlap. I'll knock up an example later if I find some time.